# How do you make a column in java swing package

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hey guys so i am making this game tic-tac-toe and wanted to know how to make another column to the right. You will understand better visually:

this is what i made now:

[image]

But if i add another button it just goes down vertically. How do i make it so it goes horizontally to the middle so i can make my tic-tac-toe game.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.xml.XMLLib.Factory;



public class TicTacToe {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    JButton row1col1;
    JButton row1col2;
    JButton row1col3;
    JButton row2col1;
    JButton row2col2;
    JButton row2col3;
    JButton row3col1;
    JButton row3col2;
    JButton row3col3;   


    public TicTacToe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        frame = new JFrame("Fds");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder
                 (10, 10, 10, 10));

        row1col1 = new JButton();
        row1col1.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row1col1);

        row1col2 = new JButton();
        row1col2.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row1col2);

        row1col3 = new JButton();
        row1col3.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row1col3);


        row2col1 = new JButton();
        row2col1.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row2col1);

        row2col2 = new JButton();
        row2col2.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row2col2);

        row2col3 = new JButton();
        row2col3.setMargin( new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        contentPane.add(row2col3);



        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }


    private static void runGUI() {
         JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
         TicTacToe greeting = new TicTacToe();
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
         run from an event-dispatching thread */
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         runGUI();
         }
         });


         }


}
```

Comment: You could use a GridLayout instead of your BoxLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) instead of the `BoxLayout`.

The grid layout manager will then take care of placing your buttons in a grid like fashion.

Something like so (untested):

```
JButton[] grid = new JButton[9];
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,1,1));
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    ...//Attach event handlers, etc.
    this.add(button);
    grid.add(button);
}
```

The above code should create a 3 x 3 grid and populate it with buttons.

Comment: How do i do that? You know? so i can adjust it to the tic tac toe? I have two create two panels?

Comment: you can just replace this line `contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` whit this one `contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));`

Comment: Ok i did that! And it worked! But just one question. now that i have it in columns, can i space out the columns?

Comment: @ewrwr: You mean having them like `|B| |B| |B|` instead of `|B|B|B|`?

Comment: of course! `contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,1,1));` You can change the gap just by changing the last two arguments of the layout constructor

Comment: @GianniB.: Yeah that's it, just wanted to confirm with the OP :).

Comment: @ewrwr: Looking at the Java Documentation is always a big help and is something you will eventually (and hopefully) get accustomed to doing).

Comment: @ewrwr it's all in the Java Documentation!! You should learn to search, read and study it because it's essential

Comment: Ok @npinti was reading the book a lot so wasnt accustomed to the docs :(

Comment: Ok @GianniB. was reading a book a lot so wasnt accustomed to the docs :(

Answer (score 2):

It's all about your layout: you have specified the BoxLayout which put the controls vertically.

Just use another one. You can find more about Layout [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box)

[GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid) seems to be perfect for your porpouse